# In what airports do I undergo US exit immigration checks, if I have a connecting flight?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights

I have booked a ticket from Detroit to India. My first flight is from Detroit to Newark (EWR) Airport, and my second is from EWR to India. Both flights are on the same ticket. Will I need to do immigration at both EWR and Detroit airport?

Comment: Why do you need to know? It might help providing better answers.

Comment: What's an "exit immigration check," please?

Answer (score 23):

In USA, there is no exit checks. That means, you don't have to go through a passport control, either in EWR or Detroit. Your details will be provided by your airline to the US government and your exit will be recorded. Your bags will be checked through to India. For India, you have to go through immigration and customs at first point of entry.

When coming in to USA, you have to go through immigration on the first point of entry. There, you have to collect your bags, go through customs and recheck the bags, which will go to final destination.

Some exceptions:

1. There might be officers from CBP that does random checks. But when departing, even if you overstay for a significant time, they won't stop you from leaving. There is no fine or criminal penalty for overstaying in US (You will be banned from entering US for some years, or will have difficulty obtaining the next visa). So, they will be happy that you are leaving on your own, without causing them expenses to detain and remove you.
2. When entering US, there are some airports, which has [US preclearance](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance) facility. In that case, you will be going through immigration and customs at that airport and will be arriving in US similar to a domestic flight. In that case, your baggage will be checked through to your final destination and there will be no checks when you arrive in the US.

Comment: To underscore the similarity, I would start the second paragraph "When coming in to USA, you have to go through immigration and customs...."  This is most notably different from the Schengen area (and most of Europe, I believe), where one clears immigration controls at the first point of entry but customs controls at the final destination.

Comment: If you want to be really thorough, you can mention that CBP sometimes spot checks departing passengers at the gate.  This would happen in EWR in this example.  I've never seen this myself, but I've read that some flights or destinations are subjected to this fairly regularly.

Comment: Your passport *will* be checked in the US when flying internationally from the US. But the purpose of the check is not an exit check. It's to ensure that you will be admitted to the country you are flying to (and avoid the airline having to repatriate you)

Comment: The passport will be checked by the airline during check-in, not by the CBP. But it WILL be checked and needs to be provided

Comment: and if you really want to, you can also mention that there are airports with many departures to the US, such as in Canada, where the US has special arrangements to do immigration at departure, in the foreign county

Comment: @phoog For Shengen, the logic makes sense. Even if they share a common immigration, customs rules can vary according to country (as I assume). So, customs at final destination makes sense. For US, it should be same for all states.

Comment: @phoog But even if the CBP determines that the passenger overstayed, they can't do anything, right? They will be happy that the passenger is leaving on their own and less headache for them. Unlike many countries, there is no criminal penalty, or fines for overstaying.

Comment: @abligh in the normal course of events, the traveler's passport is checked by the airline, but there is more to it than just fulfilling their obligations to the destination country.  (They aren't obliged to ensure that the passenger will be admitted but rather that the passenger has the required documents, a subtle but important difference.)  The airline _also_ has obligations to the country from which the flight is leaving, and in the US this includes transmitting the passport details to CBP to record the passenger's departure. Similar obligations exist elsewhere.

Comment: Anish Sheela: on customs, absolutely. Non-EU Schengen states are outside the EU customs union, and even within the EU there are various excise rates for tobacco and alcohol IIRC. On immigration, some violations do carry criminal penalties, and a simple overstay, while not criminal, incurs civil liability, including a ban if the overstay is long enough. I have read that the targeted flights are to places thought to be centers of money laundering, so the main purpose is probably to catch undeclared transport of cash, but that won't stop them from dealing with an overstay if they find one.